# Android multiple applications authentication

Tags: android, authentication, single-sign-on

good morning,

how can i do a SSO valid between my 3 apps.

i have 3 apps that should be installed on same phone. like google apps or facebook

and if i'm logged on one of them then other apps bypass the auth part.

i'm looking for good practices

thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

By default android runs each app on separated sandbox so apps can not access data from other apps. But you can run as many apps as you like under the same sandbox. In that case you can access any data from other apps (database, files, etc.)

This is only one way of sharing data and not the preferred way BTW. Another approached that highly encourage by android team is to create content providers and allow controlled access to other applications in platform. This is exactly the way you are accessing users contact database in android for example.

I don't explain how to do it here. there are plenty of resources on internet and several well explained youtube videos.

Comment: do you have any reference to facebook or google that confirm what you are saying? How did you come up with the conclusion that Google and Facebook using this technique?

Comment: You'r right there is no grantee, i made an edit to my answer. thank you